# Prevent nesting in SCSS/SASS output

Tags: css, sass, nested

With all the neat features in SCSS, it can be easy to get carried away and end up with some pretty rough CSS.

Take, for example, a classic nested rats nest -

```
.image {
    ...

    .imageWrapper {
        ...

        img {
            ...
        }
    }

    .textWrapper {
        ...

        title {
            ...
        }

        caption {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Which compiles to

```
.image {
    ...
}

.image .imageWrapper {
    ...
}

.image .imageWrapper img {
    ...
}

.image .textWrapper {
    ...
}

.image .textWrapper .title {
    ...
}

.image .textWrapper .caption {
    ...
}
```

This is not only hard to read, but a slog on processors.

Now, I'm not one to use unspecific class-names (just how long **is** too long?) so nesting has very little functional use to me, but I find it makes my pre-compiled SCSS *extremely* understandable - the ability to imply the relationship an element has with its parent and children is invaluable to both myself and the next developer who happens across my code.

**Is there any way to keep my SCSS nested in all or (preferably) part of my sheet without rendering endless child selectors in my CSS?**

Comment: Is this question for real?  If you don't want the result that comes with nesting, don't nest?  Nesting is a convenience for you so that you can avoid repeating selectors, not a requirement.

Comment: @cimmanon like I say in the question, I like what the nesting looks like in the SCSS

Comment: That's not what nesting is *for*.

Comment: @cimmanon it's what I'd like to use it for, if it's not possible it's not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `@at-root` directive.

It works by ‘jumping out’ of where you nest it in your Sass to be a the top level.

For example, you could to this :

```
.image {
    color: #333;
    @at-root {
        .imageWrapper {
            color: #666;
            img {
                color: #999;
            }
        }
    }

    .stayNested {
        background-color: #555;
    }

    @at-root {
        .textWrapper {
            color: #aaa;
            title {
                color: #ccc;
            }
            caption {
                color: #fff;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That would compile to this :

```
.image {
  color: #333;
}
.imageWrapper {
  color: #666;
}
.imageWrapper img {
  color: #999;
}
.image .stayNested {
  background-color: #555;
}
.textWrapper {
  color: #aaa;
}
.textWrapper title {
  color: #ccc;
}
.textWrapper caption {
  color: #fff;
}
```

For more info, see the [**official documentation**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root)

Comment: This is pretty much on the nose.  A little disappointed to see that it requires another level of brackets/indentation, but beggars can't be choosers.  Thanks!

Comment: @SandyGifford : You're welcome... It you're going to use the `@at-root` directive for ‘jumping out’ of your nesting, I would recommend using a naming convention like BEM (https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/), or any other naming convention that specifies a parent-child relationship by the way classes are named. That way, you can preserve the relationship with the parent selector in your SCSS through the naming of your CSS classes.

Comment: I actually **adore** BEM, and use it wherever possible - sadly when coming on to existing projects it's not always an option as a naming scheme is often (hopefully) in place.